# Split Regular expression after each repetition

Tags: python, regex, templates

I'm experimenting arround with template engines lately and am stuck in a very early stage at a regular expression.

The first Step in my template engine should be to extract all template constructs. So I wrote following regular expression:

```
# Split all relevant parts apart to merger them later on.
exp_tags = re.compile(r'({[%|{](.*)[}|%]})')
print exp_tags.split(body)
```

which works fine, until 2 template constructs are in one line. The expression then merges them together and doesn't split one by one.

Example:

```
<section>
{{title}}{{text}}
</section>
```

Should result in:

```
{'<section>', '{{title}}', 'title', '{{text}}', 'text', '</section>'}
```

But results in:

```
{'<section>', '{{title}}{{text}}', 'title}}{{text', '</section>'}
```

Anyone know how to achieve my goals with regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regular expression quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) are greedy by default. Either use the non-greedy variant of `*` by appending `?` to it:

```
r'({[%|{](.*?)[}|%]})'
```

Or use a negated character class to exclude the end delimiters.

By the way: The [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a|b]` does not mean *either `a` or `b`* but *one of the set of {`a`, `|`, `b`}* as the `|` is not interpreted as alternation but as a literal character.

Comment: Thanks for the precise and fast answer. Appreciate that.